# A Python Program to find the largest odd occurring number in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote this code but it is returning none in a couple of parameters...

```
def duplicates(list,item):
    return [i for i, x in enumerate(list) if x == item]

def largest_odd_times(L):

    count=0
    temp=0
    largest=0
    for n in L:
        if n>largest:
            largest=n
    for a in L:
        if a==largest:
            count+=1
    if count%2==0:
        for k in duplicates(L,largest):
            L.remove(largest)
            if L is None:
                break
            else:
                largest_odd_times(L)

    else:        
        return largest
```

Comment: You are forgetting to return the result of the recursive call; see the duplicate.

Comment: thank you Martijn Pieters for helping me out

Comment: its giving a wrong output in this case

Comment: largest_odd_times([3, 3, 2, 0])